# Setting up a Foreign Key - transact SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, foreign-keys, sql-server-2014, create-table

I'm experiencing an issue with the following tSQL in SQL Server 2014 when assigning a foreign key. Can someone help me in understanding what is incorrect? Thanks - JT

```
    create table dbo.tbl_Util_Cost
    (
    chr_Grade   nchar(10)    not null Primary Key,
    pct_Target  decimal(18, 2)  not null,
    mon_Cost_Per_Hour   money   not null,
    dec_Daily_Hours decimal(18, 1)  not null
    );

    create table dbo.tbl_Team_Details
   (
     num_Personal_Number    numeric(18, 0)  not null,
     chr_Name   nchar(30)    not null,
     chr_Employee_Grade nchar(10)    not null ,
     dt_Start_Date date not null,
     dt_End_Date date   not null,
     foreign key fk_Team_Details1  ( chr_Employee_Grade) references dbo.tbl_Util_Cost (chr_Grade)   
    );
```

I am getting the following error on the Foreign key -

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11 Incorrect syntax near
>   'fk_Team_Details1'

Please advice!

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong.
Here is example of correct syntax:

CONSTRAINT fk_Team_Details1  FOREIGN KEY (chr_Employee_Grade) 
REFERENCES dbo.tbl_Util_Cost (chr_Grade)

For more: [Create Foreign Key Relationships](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189049.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
foreign key fk_Team_Details1  
( chr_Employee_Grade) references dbo.tbl_Util_Cost (chr_Grade)
```

with

```
 constraint fk_Team_Details1  
 foreign key (chr_Employee_Grade) references dbo.tbl_Util_Cost (chr_Grade)
```

full script:

```
create table dbo.tbl_Util_Cost
(
chr_Grade   nchar(10)    not null Primary Key,
pct_Target  decimal(18, 2)  not null,
mon_Cost_Per_Hour   money   not null,
dec_Daily_Hours decimal(18, 1)  not null
);

create table dbo.tbl_Team_Details
(
 num_Personal_Number    numeric(18, 0)  not null,
 chr_Name   nchar(30)    not null,
 chr_Employee_Grade nchar(10)    not null ,
 dt_Start_Date date not null,
 dt_End_Date date   not null,
 constraint fk_Team_Details1  foreign key ( chr_Employee_Grade) references dbo.tbl_Util_Cost (chr_Grade)   
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the 2nd Table creation at adding Foriegn Key

```
  constraint fk_Team_Details1  foreign key  
 ( chr_Employee_Grade) references dbo.tbl_Util_Cost (chr_Grade)
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go

```
create table dbo.tbl_Util_Cost
(
chr_Grade   nchar(10)    not null Primary Key,
pct_Target  decimal(18, 2)  not null,
mon_Cost_Per_Hour   money   not null,
dec_Daily_Hours decimal(18, 1)  not null
);

create table dbo.tbl_Team_Details
(
 num_Personal_Number    numeric(18, 0)  not null,
 chr_Name   nchar(30)    not null,
 chr_Employee_Grade nchar(10)    not null ,
 dt_Start_Date date not null,
 dt_End_Date date   not null,
 constraint fk_Team_Details1  foreign key ( chr_Employee_Grade) references dbo.tbl_Util_Cost (chr_Grade)   
);
```